# Swiping page constraint Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, swipe

I have a swiping function in my game. When I press and hold RMB and move it left, it will move from image 1 to image 2 like a swiping effect. My problem is that when I swipe in the direction that does not contain an image it will drag image 1 to the side until I let go of RMB, then it will bounce back to where I was. How can I make it so that there is a constrain or collider where I won't be able to even drag it to the side where there is no image?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class PageSwipe : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler {
    private Vector3 panelLocation;
    public float percentTreshold = 0.1f;
    public float easing = 0.5f;
    public int totalpages = 2;
    private int currentPage = 1;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() {
        panelLocation = transform.position; }
    
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData data) {
        float difference = data.pressPosition.x - data.position.x;
        transform.position = panelLocation - new Vector3(difference, 0, 0);
    
    }
    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData data) {
        float percentage = (data.pressPosition.x - data.position.x) / Screen.width;
        if(Mathf.Abs(percentage) >= percentTreshold) {
            Vector3 newLocation = panelLocation;
            if (percentage > 0 && currentPage < totalpages) {
                currentPage++;
                newLocation += new Vector3(-Screen.width, 0, 0);
            }else if(percentage < 0 && currentPage > 1) {
                currentPage--;
                newLocation += new Vector3(Screen.width, 0, 0);
            }
            StartCoroutine(SmoothMove(transform.position, newLocation, easing));
            panelLocation = newLocation;
        }else{
            StartCoroutine(SmoothMove(transform.position, panelLocation, easing));
        }
    
    }
    IEnumerator SmoothMove(Vector3 startpos, Vector3 endpos, float seconds) {
        float t = 0f;
        while (t <= 1.0) {
            t += Time.deltaTime / seconds;
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startpos, endpos, Mathf.SmoothStep(0f, 1f, t));
            yield return null;        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a constraint in the `OnDrag` function that has a min/max bounds of the transform position in the X. Instead of just setting the float difference, set it as `float difference = Mathf.Clamp(data.pressPosition.x - data.position.x, MIN_X_VALUE, MAX_X_VALUE)`. That way the value that the `transform.position` is set to can never drop below/above your preset values. If you give more information as to what your objects are (Sprites, Images, Meshes) I can help you calculate these MIN_X_VALUE and MAX_X_VALUE. It is rather hard to say from just looking at this code.

Comment: I have a canvas with a child called Swipe, containing my script. The swipe has two children, each with an image component.

Comment: I tried what you said, and found my max/min value, but this makes me lose the "Swiping effect" when I try to swipe back to image 1. I put 0 in the min value so when I'm on image 1 I can't swipe to the left, only to the right where image 2 is. When I'm on image 2I want to mirror the effect and only be able to swipe left instead. The easiest way to describe what I'm looking for is to compare it to a phone's home screen. The default is a background and a set of apps, swipe right, and I will get another set of apps.

Comment: If this is in a scroll rect and is fully a UI component, set your scroll rect movement type to Clamp. It will only allow you to scroll within the bounds of your Content size. Remove the other clamp.